# Bar Mitzvah on Yom Tov

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat, minhag, yom-tov, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

In most situations a boy becomes a Bar Mitzvah and there are certain practices to mark that occasion which take place on the upcoming Shabbos. Those may include some or all of the following: getting an aliya, reading the Torah and the Haftorah, having a kiddush.

Are there any sources mentioning how to proceed when:

1. He becomes a Bar Mitzvah and the next holy day of rest is a Yom Tov?
2. His 'bo bayom', the day he actually becomes a Bar Mitzvah, falls out on a Yom Tov?
3. The day of his Bo Bayom is a Yom Tov that falls on Shabbos?

Obviously we are dealing with minhagim at best, but is the minhag to specifically engage in these practices on the Shabbos following the day he turns thirteen, or perhaps on any day similar to Shabbos, like Yom Tov.

Comment: Are there even sources that tie this celebration to a shabbat (especially as tefillin would be contraindicated then)? Some are tied to the next Torah reading (Shabbat for the sake of family and the amount of time for celebrating) but I have seen celebrations on Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: Well the funny thing about minhagim is nobody has to discuss them until someone wants to deviate, so even if it was universally accepted to do any of these things on Shabbos, it wouldn't necessarily be written.

Comment: Is אין מערבים שמחה בשמחה relevant here?

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Hamburger in is sefer on Minhag Ashkenaz (Yekkish minhagim) says the bar mitzvah should only be on Shabbos. It is not clear to me if that would also include a Yontif that falls on Shabbos.
Same as Shalom Zachor or Aufruf only being on Shabbos not on weekday Yontif.